# Persistent Volume and Kubernetes upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

What happens to the persistent volume post cluster upgrade ?
The Kubernetes cluster is for a stateful application. It has one pv and corresponding pvc for storing input data. I would like to understand if there is a way to preserve the input data during K3S upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The kubernetes PV are not created on the node disk storage: when you kill your  StatefulSet pod, It may be deployed on a different node, with the same PV.

Most of cloud providers use their block storage services as a default backend for K8S PV (ex: AWS EBS) and they provide other CSI (Container Storage Interface) drivers to use other storage services (ex: NFS service).

So when you upgrade your cluster, you can re-use your data if they are stored outside the cluster, you need just to check which CSI you are using, and read its doc to understand where it is created.